# scp is given access to a subdirectory. How to command scp to change parent directory?

Tags: ssh

When using `scp`, I am given access to a subdirectory. How should I amend the command to copy files from a different parent directory? I am using the standard `scp` command as follows:

```
scp -P port-number hostname@ip-address:path/to/file path/to/folder
```

Comment: I need  clarification. 1) To what `hostname@ip-address` belongs to? An Android device or other machine? 2) Where are you running `scp`? Are you running on device itself using ADB or terminal app, or `scp` is local to a Linux machine, in which case the hostname would be of an Android device.

Comment: @Firelord it belongs to my android device. i am running it from my Linux machine in the terminal.